# Leaflet map draggable marker events

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Everytime I click on the map I create a draggable marker with a `drag` function. It works great, however everytime I release the mouse after I dragged some marker, the `click` event of the map is triggered. How can I stop that ?

```
map.on('click',
    function (e) {
        var pos = e.latlng;
        console.log('map click event');

        var marker = L.marker(
            pos,
            {
                draggable: true
            }
        );
        marker.on('drag', function (e) {
            console.log('marker drag event');
        });
        marker.on('click', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);
        marker.addTo(map);
    }
);
```

**Edit:** `marker.on('click', L.DomEvent.stopPropagation);` This partially fixes the bug. Now if I drag the marker VERY quickly and release it, the bug still occurs, because the marker "follows" the mouse cursor in a speed slower than the speed with which I move my cursor, and so when the mouse is released, the mouse is not on the marker anymore, so the map `click` event is triggered.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can confirm that, [as you've reported](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4457), this appears to be a real bug in both 0.7x and 1.0x (on Chrome, at least; I haven't tested it elsewhere). However, there is a workaround that seems to prevent it. If you name your `click` event listener function, you can turn it off on `dragstart`, then use `setTimeout` to turn it back on a short time after `dragend`:

```
map.on('click',
  function mapClickListen(e) {
    var pos = e.latlng;
    console.log('map click event');
    var marker = L.marker(
      pos, {
        draggable: true
      }
    );
    marker.on('drag', function(e) {
      console.log('marker drag event');
    });
    marker.on('dragstart', function(e) {
      console.log('marker dragstart event');
      map.off('click', mapClickListen);
    });
    marker.on('dragend', function(e) {
      console.log('marker dragend event');
      setTimeout(function() {
        map.on('click', mapClickListen);
      }, 10);
    });
    marker.addTo(map);
  }
);
```

Here's a fiddle to test it:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/sxokLjzb/

Comment: Slick workaround. [OSRM](http://map.project-osrm.org/) seems to have their workaround too. Probably they do the same thing as you.

Comment: Actually they have the same bug too ! I reproduced it with a green marker and then dragging in quickly. It places a red marker instead of just moving the green marker.

Comment: this workaround won't work for plugin authors because the click event may be from other devs so you can't readd it later :-(